# How to display date and time(12 hour format) from seconds in java

Tags: java

Hi I have seconds as follows

```
long seconds = 1299671538L;
```

Using the above seconds I want to display the date and time(12 hour format).
I have written code as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                             "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm,a", Locale.getDefault());
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(seconds * 1000L));
System.out.println(dateString);
```

I am getting output as `Wednesday, March 9, 2011 17:22,PM`.

But I want to display `Wednesday, March 9, 2011 05:22,PM(12 hour format)`

Answer (score 15):

Use `hh` instead of `HH`. The documentation for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) describes this.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for verification.

Answer (score 4):

Use `hh` instead of `HH` for 12 hour format.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm,a", Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc?

> The following pattern letters are defined (all other characters from
>   'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are reserved):
>
> ```
> Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
> G     Era designator  Text    AD
> y     Year    Year    1996; 96
> M     Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
> w     Week in year    Number  27
> W     Week in month   Number  2
> D     Day in year     Number  189
> d     Day in month    Number  10
> F     Day of week in month    Number  2
> E     Day in week     Text    Tuesday; Tue
> a     Am/pm marker    Text    PM
> H     Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
> k     Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
> K     Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
> h     Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
> m     Minute in hour  Number  30
> s     Second in minute    Number  55
> S     Millisecond     Number  978
> z     Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST;
> ```
>
> GMT-08:00
>       Z     Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800